# In AngularJS, Adding field to Array from another json file, possible callback issue

Tags: json, angularjs, foreach

AngularJS Service: 
Get json sub-record field for import into current open array record.

I have one json file with "services" in it (id, name) services.json,
I need to forEach through them, but as I am in each service I need to open sub-record(welding.json) and grab a field(title) and add it to the current record.

NOTE: My project is a CLI type.

services.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "welding"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "carpentry"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "mechanic"
    }
]
```

= Sub-Records =

welding.json

```
{
    "category": "labor",
    "title": "Arc Welding",
    "description": "",
    "experience": "20+ Years",
    "details": ""
}
```

Expectation:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "welding",
    "title": "Arc Welding"
}
```

Comment: The AngularJS framework doesn't use callbacks. It uses promises.

Comment: How do you maintain relation between these 2 json to merge?

Comment: Notice the "name" in services.json is the name of the json data file for that service ?

Comment: What's the best reference for CLI type projects ? Most searches bring up $scope type projects which most of the time are so different they can become confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.forEach($scope.services, function (value, key) {
if(value.name == 'welding'){
    $http.get('welding.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.welding = response;
    })
     $scope.services.title=$scope.welding.title;
}});
```